# what does "painted" mean in these contexts, exactly?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, idioms, phrases, connotations

> Aren't you bitter about Amy? I thought she was the one who ditched you.
> All women are **painted** satans. So why should I even care?

What does "painted" mean in this context? Is the speaker referring to them as "being the real picture of the satan" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Painted Satan" is an unusual collocation (Google Ngram returns zero references), but "painted Jezebel" is a well-known (if somewhat archaic) phrase.

Quoting the Wiktionary definition of [**painted Jezebel**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/painted_Jezebel):

> *(obsolete, derogatory)* A Jezebel; an evil, scheming, shameless or immoral woman, especially one who uses physical attractiveness to evil ends.

Wiktionary also notes that in the 16th century, "some people believed that makeup was worn only by immoral women; hence the wearing of makeup implied immorality," because the **painted** part does indeed mean "wearing makeup." Definition number 5 of [**painted** at dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/painted) is

> 5. covered with makeup, especially to excess.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to mean "devils in disguise". (Painted, as in wearing a layer of paint for camouflage, metaphorically.)

Comment: I agree with both the idea of disguise, and that the disguise is provided by makeup.